# Do I need to specify typename in the return type of member function if the function is defined inside the body of the class?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, injected-class-name

Consider the example below:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass {
    // rest of the definition ...

    SomeClass<T>& function1() {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }

    SomeClass& function2() {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }

}
```

Is there a difference between return values of the two functions above? If not, which one should be preferred?

Comment: There's no difference, and usually the second version is preferred, requires less code duplication.

Comment: [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

Comment: Side note: you don't have to use the first form even *outside* the class template definition. This is one nice feature of trailing return types `auto SomeClass<T>::function2() -> SomeClass&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between `function1` and `function2`. Typing `SomeClass` without template arguments in the definition of `SomeClass` is an instance of using an [*injected-class-name*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name):

> The injected-class-name is the name of a class within the scope of said class.
>
> In a class template, the injected-class-name can be used either as a template name that refers to the current template, or as a class name that refers to the current instantiation.

It is subjective whether to use one over the other, but the injected class name is more maintainable as it doesn't have to be manually changed if you change the number of template parameters of `SomeClass`.

Comment: I've had issues with some older GCC versions though that are a little buggy in some cases, leaving me resorting to the full name.